# How do I disable autorun when I plug in a USB?

Tags: usb, automount

I have a mobile Internet stick that is connected through the USB. The annoying part is that the connection program automatically launches when I plug it in.

I prefer to connect to the Internet using the Network Preferences, look for the USB modem device, then click Connect. Well, of course, I already have the modem device icon up in the menu bar, so there's no need to open any additional windows.

**How do I disable autorun when I plug in a USB?**

Bonus points if I could disable autorun for this particular USB stick.

Comment: It's probably because your connection program runs in background. Try quitting it.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, do you mean it's running in the background even before I plug in the USB? (it probably installed some app the first time I used it)

Comment: Yep, that's my presumption.